# how to read file with c# from web space

Tags: c#, html, web

how to read file with c# from web space?
how to read file from "www.mysite.com/ver.txt" so if the text in file is "1"
return valu "OK" but if the text in file is "0" return valu "No".
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) class. Something like this should work:

```
HttpWebRequest  request  = (HttpWebRequest)
WebRequest.Create(url);
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
request.GetResponse();
Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();
string tempString = null;
int count = 0;

do
{
    // fill the buffer with data
    count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

    // make sure we read some data
    if (count != 0)
    {
        // translate from bytes to ASCII text
        tempString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buf, 0, count);

        // continue building the string
        sb.Append(tempString);
    }
}
while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

String text = sb.ToString();
if(text == "1")
    Console.Write("Yes");
else
    Console.Write("No");
```

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/HttpWebFetch.aspx